# pip3 install having issues in installing certain packages

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip

I keep encountering this issue, wherein - whenever I try to install a package using pip3 - it keeps on having this issue where it is unable to create the wheel for a certain package/process and hence, the desired package does not get installed as a result.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3155]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\(redacted)>pip3 install pandas
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.2.1.tar.gz (4.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [71 lines of output]
      Collecting meson-python==0.13.1
        Using cached meson_python-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
      Collecting meson==1.2.1
        Using cached meson-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Collecting Cython==3.0.5
        Using cached Cython-3.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting numpy<=2.0.0.dev0,>1.22.4
        Using cached numpy-1.26.4.tar.gz (15.8 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [38 lines of output]
        Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
          Using cached ninja-1.11.1.1.tar.gz (132 kB)
          Installing build dependencies: started
          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
        Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
          Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
          Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
          error: subprocess-exited-with-error

          Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
          exit code: 1

          [15 lines of output]
          C:\Users\(redacted)\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9ee0ft9k\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:308: UserWarning: git archive did not support describe output
            warnings.warn("git archive did not support describe output")
          C:\Users\(redacted)\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9ee0ft9k\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:327: UserWarning: unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)
            warnings.warn("unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)")
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "C:\Users\(redacted)\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9ee0ft9k\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
              cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\(redacted)\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9ee0ft9k\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
              self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\(redacted)\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9ee0ft9k\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
              raise SKBuildError(msg) from err

          Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
          [end of output]

          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
          ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
        Failed to build ninja
        ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1

      See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried updating the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES, refreshing cmd, etc. Any advice or possible solution to this predicament would be extremely appreciated.